# How do I get the return from button

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button, mainloop

how do i get the return from button command
also tried without lambda doesn't work

```
import tkinter as tk

#value = ''
def button(e,f):
    #global value
    value = e.get()
    f.destroy()
    return value

def display(root):
    value=''
    f = tk.Frame(root,width=200 ,height=200)
    f.place(x=0,y=0)
    
    e = tk.Entry(f,width=200,font=17)
    e.place(x=0,y=0)
    
    b = tk.Button(f,text="submit",command = lambda : value == button(e,f))
    b.place(x=0,y=40)

    return value

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
value = display(root)
print(value)
root.mainloop()
#print(value)
```

#print(value) <-- prints with  global but only when i close root window

Comment: Do you know that the return `value` from `display()` is empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t get the return value from a function called from an event.

If you want the print to work after `mainloop` exits, you will need to have the function set a global or instance variable.

Comment: I want  display to return the entry  when i press submit  button inside mainloop,
or any other way to get the entry when button is clicked inside mainloop,

Answer (score 0):

> any other way to get the entry when button is clicked inside mainloop

The function `button` is executed *inside mainloop*, so you already have the entry value *inside mainloop*; you can do everything you want to do with it right there.